# Can we get sum of several columns in a mysql table

Tags: mysql

Can we get sum of several columns that have intergers in a mysql table?

```
A   B   C   D
1   0   2   3
```

I need to get sum of all columns. I have one row.

Comment: Do you mean the sum of the value's of the record, or the sum of all the collumns?

Comment: why did you down vote?

Comment: the sum of all the collumns

Comment: I didn't downvote, I'am asking you to clarify something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the data model is awkward, however,

```
select a+b+c+d
from ...
where ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select suma+sumb+sumc+sumd from
(select sum(A) as suma,sum(B) as sumb,sum(C)as sumc,sum(D) as sumd 
from tab) mytab
```